# Instantiate new "players" in a sub folder in Hierarchy view | Unity networking with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, unity-networking

I am using Vuforia for creating a basic multiplayer AR project. My immediate requirement is to display multiple players in the same scene - each player is to be controlled by a separate device connected to the same network.

My current Hierarchy view is like this:

[image: Initial Hierarchy view - using Vuforia]

According to Vuforia, all assets to be rendered should go under **ImageTarget**. I have a player prefab which basically contains the UnityChan character along with a small player movement script (tap/ click to move to a point). The network manager is responsible for instantiating player for each device (i.e. "client" or connection) from that prefab.

[image: Network Manager]

However the player objects are created in the root folder in Hierarchy view. So they are never visible in the actual AR scene. Here's the hierarchy view during "play" mode (2 devices connected) -[image: Hierarchy view - during play mode; 2 connections]

So my question is: how can I instantiate the "players" inside the **ImageTarget** folder instead, so that they are visible in my AR scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the parent.

Something like this

```
Transform imageTargetTransform = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ImageTarget>().transform;

Player player1 = Instantiate<Player>(playerPrefab);
player1.tranform.parent = imageTargetTransform;
```

IDK your class names though so youll need to adapt the above for your needs.

Comment: The players get auto instantiated by the Network Manager (as shown in the second image). I do not have a script that manually spawns players for each device that connects to the network.

Comment: the point stays. to get them "in the folder" you set the parent. find the Player GameObject, find the ImageTarget GameObject, link their transforms.

Comment: but admitably, i have no clue about vuforia. i only answered the question about how to parent objects.

Comment: Done. The script on the player prefab now contains this snippet inside the start method.


    Transform imageTargetTransform = GameObject.Find("ImageTarget/GameObject").transform;
    transform.parent = imageTargetTransform;



However, the player character still isn't showing up in the scene.

Comment: My bad. The character was not visible because it had scaled down. Rectified it. Thanks a lot for the answer.